# gesture detection with kinect v2 using javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, kinect

I'm trying to develop an app in Javascript using kinect v2. I need to load gestures stored in a gbd file, and then detect them. The problem is that I couldn't find any way to do that. I searched for books, tutorials, post, or previous experiences but, I couldn't find anything. I also try looking the API for Javascript but it wasn't very helpful.

Post everything that can be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to write a kinect app using Javascript.The MSDN comunity was very helpful and put me on the right way. https://github.com/angelaHillier/DiscreteGestureBasics-HTML.git

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to catch Gesture because the Kinect will only provide you the raw data in the JavaScript SDK.

Read this thread on Microsoft forum:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c285b9ae-a8d3-4ed7-bcf6-0b05b03deebf/developing-with-javascript-vs-wpf-c?forum=kinectv2sdk

I made a presentation available here on this subject: (In french ;)) http://fr.slideshare.net/MickaelDumand/kinect-pour-les-dveloppeur-web

Comment: I apologize in advance if this is a noob question, but, if we only have RAW data in JavaScript, does it means that the only way I could manage to recognize, for example,  a slide left gesture is tracking each joint of the body?
I'm still on the project, I managed to import a GBD file, and create all the visualBodyBuilder structure, but, as you said, the event associated to the moves on the GBD isn't triggered

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try to make visualBodyBuilder work with javaScript but yes, unfortunately i think the only way is to track the hand joint on the body.

I made a first approach to structure that kind of things here:
https://github.com/ekino/ek-winjs-kinect

Maybe you can look at the /src folder and add the swipe gesture that you need.

Comment: After a quick comment on the MSDN link that you posted [(link)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c285b9ae-a8d3-4ed7-bcf6-0b05b03deebf/developing-with-javascript-vs-wpf-c?forum=kinectv2sdk) I think that is fair saying that is possible the gesture recognition.